# Trouble with [ sign

Tags: typography

I need to type [x] (for equivalence class of x under some equivalence relation). Problem is: latex thinks that now x should appear in the literature section of the document, hence does not want to compile. So, please help.

Comment: You can certainly add `[x]` or `$[x]$` everywhere except at places where LaTeX may think it is an option, i.e. `\\[x]` may give unexpected results. Just try `{$[x]$}` for instance and provide a small document that illustrates your point in case this does not work.

Comment: As @marmot points out, `\\[x]` will get you into trouble.  This can be overcome with `\\\relax[x]` if you need a `[x]` to occur after a math line break.

Comment: If you happen to be using the `[x]` in an optional argument, then you need to add an extra brace group: `{[x]}`. However, it might be a good idea to define a macro `\newcommand*{\EquivClass}[1]{[#1]}`.

Comment: you guessed the point, yeah I used \\[x]

Comment: how about `\left[x\right]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Loading `mathtools`, you might de define in your preamble

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\eqclass}{[}{]}
```

and type `\eqclass{x}`. In addition, you'll have a starred version (`\eqclass*`), which adds a pair of implicit `\left \right` in front of the delimiters. You also may fine tune the size of the brackets with an optional argument: e.g. `\eqclass[\Big]{x^{p^n}}`.